# Running out of browser causes an exception in silverlight application

Tags: silverlight, web-applications, browser

I made a game in Silverlight application and I added it a button to install it to the computer, but when I click the install button I get this exception:
Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component

I used the instructions to configure an Application for Out-of-Browser from this website:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/he-il/library/dd833073(en-us,VS.95).aspx

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

One thing that causes this often is using the DOM bridge - it's not available OOB, so trying to access it will throw an Exception.

You can avoid that by checking HtmlPage.IsEnabled before accessing the DOM bridge.

Comment: Can you please explain more about it? How to do it? Where do I access the DOM bridge? I am a student so I don't know very well how it works...

Comment: The DOM bridge is basically stuff in the System.Windows.Browser namespace (in System.Windows.Browser.dll).